# How to separate output and input in the command line?

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a simple program that takes input of a time and message and outputs a message at every interval of time. The problem I am having is that when a user tries inputting a new timer and a previous timer displays its message it breaks up the input.

I wanted to know how one could make separate fields for the input and output, so they don't overlap. The program's language is C and I cannot find anything on-line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. From your description, you seem to be seeking a system such that if you have a program, call it `dribbler`, that writes a message every _n_ seconds to standard output, and you run it in background, and then you have the user typing another command: given that, you don't want `dribbler` to write while the user has unread input typed. Is that right? If so, there's no trivial way to do it. The nearest approach I can think of is the SIGTTOU signal which halts a process when it writes to a terminal but isn't the foreground process.

Comment: If you want actual separate *fields*, then you want something like `ncurses` for UNIX-like systems, or some other terminal handling library more generally.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a lot on how portable you want it to be, and what platform you are targeting.

For very simple applications [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) can suffice. Else look into libraries, ([*ncurses*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) is powerful), [`tput`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tput) (if you are on *NIX) and so on.

If you decide to play around with console codes remember that `echo -e "\033c"` (normally) reset all terminal settings to default.

Here is a crude (Linux) example using ANSI escapes to display a clock and last command. Using `SIGALRM` for the sake of simplicity.

There is more on the subject [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>           /* alarm() */

int lines = 3;                /* Store how many lines we have. */

/* Print current time every second at first line.. */
void prnt_clock()
{
        time_t tt;
        struct tm *tm;
        char buf[80];

        time(&tt);
        tm = localtime(&tt);
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%H:%M:%S", tm);
        fprintf(stdout,
                "\033[s"            /* Save cursor position. */
                "\033[%dA"          /* Move cursor up d lines. */
                "\r"                /* Moves cursor to beginning of line. */
                "%s"                /* String to print. */
                "\033[u"            /* Restore cursor position. */
                ,
                lines,
                buf
        );
        fflush(stdout);

        alarm(1);
}

/* Print last command entered at third line. */
void prnt_cmd(char *cmd)
{
        fprintf(stdout,
                "\033[s\033[%dA\r\033[KLast cmd: %s\033[u",
                lines - 2, cmd
        );
        fflush(stdout);
}

/* Empty the stdin line */
void process_input(char c)
{
        char buf[32];
        int i = 0;

        ++lines;
        while (c != '\n' && i < 31) {
                buf[i++] = c;
                c = getchar();
        }
        buf[i] = 0x00;
        if (c != '\n')
                while (getchar() != '\n')
                        ;
        prnt_cmd(buf);
}

/* Signal handler. */
void sig_alarm(int sig)
{
        if (sig == SIGALRM) {
                signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);
                prnt_clock();
                signal(SIGALRM, sig_alarm);
        }
}

int main(void /* int argc, char *argv[] */)
{
        char prompt[16] = "\033[1;31m$\033[0m "; /* We want bold red $ */
        int c;

        signal(SIGALRM, sig_alarm);
        fprintf(stdout,
                "\n"                        /* line for clock  (line 1. )*/
                "---------------------------------------------------\n"
                "Enter q to quit.\n"        /* line for status (line 3.) */
                "%s"                        /* prompt          (line 4+) */
                ,
                prompt
        );
        prnt_clock();

        while (1) {
                c = getchar();
                if (c == 'q')
                        break;
                process_input(c);
                fprintf(stdout, "%s", prompt);
                fflush(stdout);
        }

        return 0;
}
```